# How to plot an informative stratified surface graph?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly, rgl

I want to plot 3D data `d1` that is stratified by *n*. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854201/6574038) I achieved following solution with `rgl` so far, which already looks nice though I couldn't find a way to rotate the plot to the best perspective there. More straightforward in this regard seems to be `plotly`, where one can rotate the graph with the mouse. The latter also already has the color shade I need with corresponding legend. Though in both ways I don't understand how to save the graph resp. how to knit it into rmarkdown what I'm intending to do. I'm not depending on a particular package, just want the following:

- strata
- color/texture shade w/ legend
- savable, knitable

Here my attempt, data below.

```
car::some(d1, 5)
#        n   x   y        value
# 37  1000 0.0 0.0 0.000000e+00
# 93  2000 0.3 0.2 2.500834e-04
# 101 2000 0.4 0.4 3.201067e-04
# 111 4000 0.0 0.2 2.400160e-05
# 142 4000 0.5 0.3 6.400427e-05

# change levels
levels <- levels(d1$n)  # preserve for later
d1$n <- as.factor(as.numeric(d1$n))

# arrayer
arrayIt <- function(x){
  # makes array of d1 by x, y, z
  d <- sqrt(nrow(x)/length(unique(x[, 1])))  # dim. of matrices
  ar <- array(NA, c(d, d, 3))  # init. array
  ar[, , 1] <- matrix(x[, 2], d, d)  # x
  ar[, , 2] <- matrix(x[, 3], d, d)  # y
  ar[, , 3] <- matrix(x[, 4], d, d)  # z
  return(ar)
}

# list of 4 arrays for each  n
ls1 <- lapply(seq_along(unique(d1[, 1])), function(n) arrayIt(d1[d1[, 1] == n, ]))

# plot
library(rgl)
lapply(seq_along(unique(d1$n)), function(i){
  x <- ls1[[i]][,,1]
  y <- ls1[[i]][,,2]
  z <- ls1[[i]][,,3]
  persp3d(x, y, z, col = i, alpha = .5, add = i > 1)  # MARK
})
```

[image]

E.g. `plotly` already provides color shade and legend, which is very informative but `plot_ly` won't work in the `lapply` above, I also didn't find an option how to add a stratum.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z, type = "surface")  # inserted at MARK didn't work
```

[image]

In sum, the desired result would be something like the intersection of both graphs.

## *Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(n = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("500", "1000", "2000", 
                                                                               "4000"), class = "factor"), x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 
                                                                                                                 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                                                                                                 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 
                                                                                                                 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
                                                                                                                 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
                                                                                                                 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                                                                                                 0.5), y = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
                                                                                                                             0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 
                                                                                                                             0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 
                                                                                                                             0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                             0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                             0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
                                                                                                                             0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 
                                                                                                                             0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 
                                                                                                                             0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                             0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                             0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
                                                                                                                             0.5), value = c(0, 0.000253671562082777, 0.00048064085447263, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000680907877169559, 0.000854472630173565, 0.00100133511348465, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000253671562082777, 0.00048064085447263, 0.000680907877169559, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000854472630173565, 0.00100133511348465, 0.0011214953271028, 
                                                                                                                                             0.00048064085447263, 0.000680907877169559, 0.000854472630173565, 
                                                                                                                                             0.00100133511348465, 0.0011214953271028, 0.00121495327102804, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000680907877169559, 0.000854472630173565, 0.00100133511348465, 
                                                                                                                                             0.0011214953271028, 0.00121495327102804, 0.00128170894526035, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000854472630173565, 0.00100133511348465, 0.0011214953271028, 
                                                                                                                                             0.00121495327102804, 0.00128170894526035, 0.00132176234979973, 
                                                                                                                                             0.00100133511348465, 0.0011214953271028, 0.00121495327102804, 
                                                                                                                                             0.00128170894526035, 0.00132176234979973, 0.00133511348464619, 
                                                                                                                                             0, 0.000126751167444963, 0.000240160106737825, 0.000340226817878586, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000426951300867245, 0.000500333555703803, 0.000126751167444963, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000240160106737825, 0.000340226817878586, 0.000426951300867245, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000500333555703803, 0.000560373582388259, 0.000240160106737825, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000340226817878586, 0.000426951300867245, 0.000500333555703803, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000560373582388259, 0.000607071380920614, 0.000340226817878586, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000426951300867245, 0.000500333555703803, 0.000560373582388259, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000607071380920614, 0.000640426951300867, 0.000426951300867245, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000500333555703803, 0.000560373582388259, 0.000607071380920614, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000640426951300867, 0.000660440293529019, 0.000500333555703803, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000560373582388259, 0.000607071380920614, 0.000640426951300867, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000660440293529019, 0.00066711140760507, 0, 6.33544514838279e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000120040013337779, 0.000170056685561854, 0.000213404468156052, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000250083361120373, 6.33544514838279e-05, 0.000120040013337779, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000170056685561854, 0.000213404468156052, 0.000250083361120373, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000280093364454818, 0.000120040013337779, 0.000170056685561854, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000213404468156052, 0.000250083361120373, 0.000280093364454818, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000303434478159386, 0.000170056685561854, 0.000213404468156052, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000250083361120373, 0.000280093364454818, 0.000303434478159386, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000320106702234078, 0.000213404468156052, 0.000250083361120373, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000280093364454818, 0.000303434478159386, 0.000320106702234078, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000330110036678893, 0.000250083361120373, 0.000280093364454818, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000303434478159386, 0.000320106702234078, 0.000330110036678893, 
                                                                                                                                             0.000333444481493831, 0, 1.26675111674112e-05, 2.40016001066738e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             3.40022668177879e-05, 4.26695113007534e-05, 5.00033335555704e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             1.26675111674112e-05, 2.40016001066738e-05, 3.40022668177879e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             4.26695113007534e-05, 5.00033335555704e-05, 5.60037335822388e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             2.40016001066738e-05, 3.40022668177879e-05, 4.26695113007534e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             5.00033335555704e-05, 5.60037335822388e-05, 6.06707113807587e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             3.40022668177879e-05, 4.26695113007534e-05, 5.00033335555704e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             5.60037335822388e-05, 6.06707113807587e-05, 6.40042669511301e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             4.26695113007534e-05, 5.00033335555704e-05, 5.60037335822388e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             6.06707113807587e-05, 6.40042669511301e-05, 6.60044002933529e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             5.00033335555704e-05, 5.60037335822388e-05, 6.06707113807587e-05, 
                                                                                                                                             6.40042669511301e-05, 6.60044002933529e-05, 6.66711114074272e-05
                                                                                                                             )), .Names = c("n", "x", "y", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -144L
                                                                                                                             ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not sure why rotation isn't working for you.  What output format do you need?

Comment: @user2554330 see my comment to your answer

Comment: I don't have an answer to this one...  But if you want PDF output, it's hard. Interactive graphics in PDF are not well supported by viewers.  You could try `rgl::writeASY`, but it's likely to be disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `add_surface()` in plotly... And your data needs to be in matrix form for the surface plot. The plotly website has decent documentation for all sorts of plots. https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/. To get only one color scale set `showscale==FALSE` in the `plotly` command and then turn it back on for one of the plots.

```
z <- lapply(unique(data$n), 
            function(x) as.matrix(reshape(data[data$n==x,-1], 
                                          idvar = "x", timevar = "y", direction = "wide") ))

plot_ly(showscale=FALSE) %>% add_surface(z=~z[[1]][, -1], cmin=min(data$value), cmax=max(data$value), showscale=TRUE) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~z[[2]][, -1], cmin=min(data$value), cmax=max(data$value)) %>%
  add_surface(z=~z[[3]][,-1], cmin=min(data$value), cmax=max(data$value)) %>%
  add_surface(z~z[[4]][,-1], cmin=min(data$value), cmax=max(data$value))
```

### Old plot with `cmin` `cmax` unset

[image]

### New plot with `cmin` and `cmax` set so that z value is colored consistently across all strata

[image]

Comment: Looks very convincing though I could not bring the legend to appear, e.g. by ` %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE)`. I want to knit to a pdf with rmarkdown (usually static plots are knitted fine to pdf). I was just trying but it doesn't seem that easily, though HTML works perfectly. Possibly one could specify the values of a particular perspective and put out a static plot?

Comment: Have a look at this thread about knitting pdfs with plotly graphics: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/889

Comment: Yields *Warning message: 'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'showscale'*, no legend

Comment: Please note where I have set `showscale` in my post. Try changing that to TRUE. If you want only one color scale you will need to set `showscale==FALSE`  in each `add_surface`

Comment: Ahh, you're right sorry, I didn't notice! Great answer thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just as a different view on your data - because the four surfaces in single 3D plot are looking a little too busy - you can try to use contour lines and coloring on the `value`. (I'm not sure what particular aspect of the data set you need to stress/analyze.)

[image: contour lines]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value), interpolate = T) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value), bins = 15) +
  facet_wrap(~ n, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

Comment: Indeed interesting, though I need the other version. But I'll keep this definitely in mind, thanks!